# OAuth integration error

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have integrated `OAuth Framework` in the application with the help of cocoa pod as per the information given in [this GitHub installation page](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2#installation)?

I am using Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2 . When I try to build the app i am getting the following errors:

[image]

I do not understand why am I getting so many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version. The syntax for Swift 3 is very different from Swift 2.2

From the installation page:

> OAuth2 requires Xcode 8, the built framework can be used on OS X 10.9 or iOS 8 and later. Happy to accept pull requests, please see CONTRIBUTING.md

You can find the correct release [in the project's releases page](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/releases)

Comment: i have included the particular version's project file into my project , and now i am getting error "no such module OAuth2" , and i have included the framework into the embedded binaries as well .

Comment: Project->Clean. Rebuild. Maybe delete derived data & rebuild